# Umbraco Decrypting using MachineKey Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, umbraco, machinekey

I want to first encrypt some nodes in Umbraco's content editor. The code below is the one I use for encryption. I use MachineKey.Protect for this.

```
        try
        {
            MailMessage message1 = new MailMessage();
            MailMessage message2 = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            string AfsenderEmail = model.Email;
            string AfsenderNavn = model.Name;

            string toAddress = Umbraco.Content(rootNode.Id).mailDerSendesTil;
            message1.From = new MailAddress(toAddress);
            message2.From = new MailAddress(toAddress);

            message1.Subject = $"{Umbraco.Content(rootNode.Id).overskriftPaaDenMailViFaar}";
            message1.Subject = message1.Subject.Replace("AfsenderEmail", AfsenderEmail);
            message1.Subject = message1.Subject.Replace("AfsenderNavn", AfsenderNavn);
            message1.Body = $"{Umbraco.Content(rootNode.Id).beskedViFaarNaarBeskedenSendes}";
            message1.Body = message1.Body.Replace("AfsenderEmail", AfsenderEmail);
            message1.Body = message1.Body.Replace("AfsenderNavn", AfsenderNavn);


            message1.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));


            client.Send(message1);

            message2.Subject = $"{Umbraco.Content(rootNode.Id).overskriftPaaMeddelelsenAfsenderenFaar}";
            message2.Subject = message2.Subject.Replace("AfsenderEmail", AfsenderEmail);
            message2.Subject = message2.Subject.Replace("AfsenderNavn", AfsenderNavn);
            message2.Body = $"{Umbraco.Content(rootNode.Id).beskedAfsenderenFaarNaarBeskedenSendes}";
            message2.Body = message2.Body.Replace("AfsenderEmail", AfsenderEmail);
            message2.Body = message2.Body.Replace("AfsenderNavn", AfsenderNavn);

            message2.To.Add(new MailAddress(AfsenderEmail));

            client.Send(message2);

            var beskederNode = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.Alias.Equals("Besked"));

            var encryptName = MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.Name));
            var encryptEmail = MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.Email));
            var encryptMessage = MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.Message));

            string nameEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptName);
            string emailEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptEmail);
            string messageEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptMessage);

            var newContent = contentService.CreateContent(nameEncrypted, beskederNode.Id, "mails");

            newContent.SetValue("fra", nameEncrypted);
            newContent.SetValue("eMail", emailEncrypted);
            newContent.SetValue("besked", messageEncrypted);

            var result = contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(newContent);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Contact Form Error", ex);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

    }
```

This is where I Try to decrypt my code again. It throws an exception (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.') when I call MachineKey.Unprotect(nameDecrypted) and I cannnot find my mistake. I think it maybe has somethimg to do with my Encoding and Decoding?

```
    private void EditorModelEventManager_SendingContentModel(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext sender, EditorModelEventArgs<Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing.ContentItemDisplay> e)
    {
        var node = e.Model.Properties.ToList();
        if (e.Model.IsChildOfListView && e.Model.ContentTypeAlias == "mails")
        {
            string nameDecrypt = node.Where(x => x.Alias.ToLower() == "fra").Select(x => x.Value).First().ToString();
            Byte[] nameDecrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nameDecrypt);
            var name = e.Model.Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Alias.ToLower() == "fra");
            Byte[] decryptName = MachineKey.Unprotect(nameDecrypted);
            string nameReady = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptName);
            name.Value = $"{nameReady}";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The byte array that comes out the back-end of System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData probably can't be written properly to the ntext field that Umbraco set up for that property in the database. You encrypt the data (works fine) then Umbraco attempts to write it to the db, then the editor reads whatever garbled junk got written, but now it won't decrypt. That's why base64 encoding the encrypted data and then base64 decoding before decrypting is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(), I used Convert.FromBase64String().